# Does scala Futures materialize exceptions?

Tags: scala, concurrency

it seems that I am missing some important concept for scala futures  and I would appriciate if someone more experienced could bring some more clarification as I am a bit confused now.

I watched some lessons from Erick Maijer on Scala monands:

Try[T] - computation which may fail

Future[T] - computation which takes time and may fail

I am particulary concernd with Exception which may happen inside a Future, are those transformed to Failed(exception)?

Based on what I have tried my current understanding is not correct otherwise the type would be Future[Try[T]].

```
val f = Future{ throw new FileNotFoundException()}
val f2 = f.map{res => "Success"}
val fr =Await.result(f2,30 seconds)
```

Results in:

```
f: scala.concurrent.Future[Nothing] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@1e86394
f2: scala.concurrent.Future[String] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@17dba83
java.io.FileNotFoundException
    at com.ss.rg.service.image.storage.A$A115$A$A115$$anonfun$f$1.apply(StorageTests.sc4056554885605566011.tmp:11)
    at com.ss.rg.service.image.storage.A$A115$A$A115$$anonfun$f$1.apply(StorageTests.sc4056554885605566011.tmp:11)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Or am I missing something important here. Future body should be exception free code and all exception should be propagated outside via Future.failed?

Than the correct implementation could be as follows

```
val f : Future[String]= {
  val p = Promise[String]
  val ff = Future{
    p.complete(Try(throw new FileNotFoundException()))
  }
  p.future
}
val f2 = f.map{res => "Success"}
val fr =Await.result(f2,30 seconds)
```

Could someone more experienced clarify this?

Thanks

Based on the feedback for this question I came to the following implementation. Since I am seasoned java developer any unhandeled Exception makes me worry. So if my undersanding is correct, following implementation is Ok since any exception is transformed to Future.failed and nio doesn't need any special clean up asfk.

```
object LocalStore extends Storage {
  import java.io.FileOutputStream
  import java.nio.ByteBuffer

  override def store(location: String, content: Array[Byte])(implicit exec: Executor): Future[String] = Future {
    require(!location.isEmpty)

    val fout = new FileOutputStream(location)
    val chanell = fout.getChannel
    val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(content.length)

    buffer.put(content)
    buffer.flip()
    chanell.write(buffer)
    location
  }
}
```

What if there is some finally necessary? Does scala offer a way how to handle that?

Comment: Future#onComplete callback has both `Success` and `Failure`. In case of an `Exception` inside a Future the exception is set to the `Failure` case.

Comment: Your first implementation is the better one. The culprit is `Await.result`, which throws the exception if the future fails.

Comment: I tried that as well with pattern match with both cases and println non of those got printed.  That the reason for rather elementar question

Comment: note that internally the value a `Future` wraps is an `Option[Try[A]]` (Option since it might not yet be completed): https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L170

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Whether inside the Future code which may throw Exception must be wrapped inside try/catch. Travis has already probably answered that